# Change nuxt js Auth cookies name

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Is there any way to change the Nuxt js auth cookies name?

[image]

I know you can change the prefix of the cookie.

do I need to extend the current schema and override methods?

Comment: Did you use `'@nuxtjs/auth-next'` in your `nuxt`?

Comment: @DengSihan yes!

Answer (score 0):

This one should work fine IMO
`nuxt.config.js`

```js
auth: {
  strategies: {
    local: {
      token: {
        property: 'my_cool_token',
      },
    },
  },
},
```

Comment: I think the `property ` is the token key name you get from your auth endpoint response like ```JSON {token (this one) : 'wsdw3',refresh_token:'sdsdsd'}```.  this will not change the cookie name

Comment: @Chinese_hacker_lm I don't have my former's company backend to try it out again, but this is what I used to have the actual cookie locally. The other one, is another option. Did you tried this one?

Comment: I already have this part in my config. so it's not it :\